# creating a data structure at specific memory location in c

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I'm working on an embedded mcu that has two cores which can both see an area of memory beginning at 0x80000000.

The ADC is connected to one core and a radio is connected to another. I want to write the data value received by the ADC to this memory address so that the other core can read it.

Would somebody be able to help me figure out how to do this? The is no micro OS, it is bare metal.

Would I create a pointer to struct at a specific address?

I have two values in an array, how would I get them into the struct?

```
#define NUM_SAMPLES_POLLED (2)
uint16_t samples_polled[NUM_SAMPLES_POLLED]
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case you'd assign the address directly to a pointer:

```
char *memdata = (char *)0x80000000;
```

Keep in mind that this behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: Maybe.  That has implementation-defined behavior.  The implementation actually in use might require a different mechanism, or might even make no provision at all for the desired behavior.

Comment: That's a bad approach. Using a section and the linker would be the correct way. But there are more measure necessary to share data.

Comment: "I need one core to write data to this address so that the other can read from it." may involve need to co-ordinate access between the 2 cores - maybe using `volatile, +atomic_, etc.  but that is beyond OP's post, yet likely a subsequent issue.

Comment: @chux: If OP has to ask about that, I have serious doubts he will be aware about these issues. These mechanisms likely call for a `struct` or multiple variables for synchronisation, so the simple `char *`-approach is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @flyswatter: I could and I have done this on various architectures, but this is no coding service and this is not my project.

Comment: @flyswatter: In case you didn't read the comments: it is not **that** simple to get it right. This is exactly the problem you first should explore.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I create an array at this exact address with some values?

The C language does not define any mechanism for assigning variables to specific addresses.  Indeed, no such mechanism would likely be viable in a hosted C implementation, for substantially all modern hosted implementations rely on an underlying OS with virtual memory.

Inasmuch as you are presumably writing for a freestanding implementation (given that the target is an embedded MCU), it is likely that there is a mechanism for what you ask.  The one suggested by @dbush would then be a good candidate, but only by checking your documentation can you be sure.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to read your tool-chain's documentation on defining and using shared memory.

Comment: What does shared memory have to do with it?

Comment: Nothing at all, obviously... or perhaps everything. rtfm

Answer (score 1):

Array is not an object. Array in "c" is just a representation of data. so you cannot create it or destroy(or release it). you can just access it, i.e read and/or write.

```
void* ptr=(void*)0x80000000;
int* arr_of_int = (int*)ptr;   //access memory location as array of int
arr_of_int[0] = 0x100;          //write value to your array
int i = arr_of_int[10] ;        // read value from array
```

or

```
char* arr_of_char = (char*)ptr;  // access memory as array of char
arr_of_char[0] = 'A';
```

you have to make sure that you are actually allowed to access this address from with in your program as OS kernel(if you are running code as user program) will forbid direct physical addressing. In that case you need to use address translation function to calculate virtual address corresponding to physical address.

Comment: Arrays **are** objects. Sorry, I'm out of downvotes today. And messing with `void *` is nonsense. Any reason you assume an OS? OP mentions an MCU, so there is likely none or just a lightweight OS like FreeRTOS without memory management.

Comment: @Olaf Perhaps earlier you had a comment that pointers are not objects.  AFAIK, pointers and arrays are _derived types_ from _objects_ C11 §6.2.5 20.

Comment: @chux: Where did I state that? Anyway, an array is not a pointer (but a pointer is an object, too). The term "object is clearly defined in 3.15: "**object**: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values".